# How to get slowest queries on SQL 2005, without requiring compability change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

I was reading this fabulous list of sql dba scripts at http://www.sqldbtools.com/Scripts.aspx, not affiliated with them. And I want to run this query...

```
select top 10
    qs.execution_count,
    st.dbid,
    DB_NAME(st.dbid) as DbName,
    st.text from sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs cross
apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
st order by execution_count desc
```

But for our production server, it is way too risky, to change compatibility modes, is there a script i can use that doesn't require that?

Answer (score 3):

Your query will work on SQL Server 2005, as long as you don't run it in context of the database with the lower compat level

```
USE master
GO
select top 10
    qs.execution_count, st.dbid, DB_NAME(st.dbid) as DbName, st.text
from 
    sys.dm_exec_query_stats as qs
    cross apply
    sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st order by execution_count desc
```

From Paul Randall's [Misconceptions about running DMVs on databases with lower compatibility levels](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Misconceptions-about-running-DMVs-on-database-with-lower-compatibility-levels.aspx)

Comment: But it's the lower compat level that i need the data on what the slowest queries are of...I can run it on our development server. But I didn't want to take any risks with server stability by changing compat level on production.